# High Temperature Humidity Sensor

Tags: temperature, humidity

Where can I get a high temperature humidity sensor for  temperatures up to 700 or 800 degree Fahrenheit (~ 370 or 425 °C)?

Comment: This is a shopping question, it is forbidden on this site: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The moisture measurement solutions from MAC INSTRUMENTS, provided in the link below, have range up to 1200<sup>o</sup>F. These might suite your requirement.

http://www.macinstruments.com/